# Redirect facebook autentication to server and then app

Tags: facebook, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to develop a server side login with facebook in my mobile app.

The app is develped using jQuery mobile and wrapped with Phonegap build.

The server side is in python.

Now I need the structure of the login to be like this:

```
    app -> myServer -> Facebook -> myServer -> app
```

My problem is: how can I redirect from my server to my app?

I can't use the facebook redirect because it goes to my server, not my app. At that point I'm "stuck" on my server and I want to go back to my app.

I tried to get the current url from my app using document.URL but when I try to access it from the server I get this error:

```
you do not have permission to open this page file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

Thanks to anyone who can/will answer.

Comment: Phonegap apps require local resources (hence the file:///) so I'm not sure what your server is trying to do. Also are you using the Facebook plugin for Phonegap? https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Comment: @JamesPearce I'm using phonegap just as a wrapper, so no: I'm not using the plugin. All the app is written using jQuery mobile. I'm working on ubuntu so I have some issue installing phonegap for iOS since it seems to require xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using childbrowser plugin.

In phonegap build

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins

Comment: Ciack404: How do you manage to do this, I am stuck in a same situation. I have managed to `app -> myServer -> Fitbit -> myServer` but the path from 'myServer -> app', I am expecting a solution from you. Please help

Comment: I haven't touched this for one year so I'm not 100% sure, but if I remember well after you get your response on the server side (from FB or whatever) you must send the needed data to your app in the format you need. Does that helps?